# How do I change the value of a form element to the ID of a selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

Ok, so I have this list and I am using jQuery to make it selectable with the following code:

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#server_list" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

List:

```
<ul id="server_list">
{foreach from=$servers item=server}
<li id="{$server.id}"><img src="{$url}/images/serverstatus.php?name={$server.name}&status={$server.status}&port={$server.port}&playercount={$server.playercount}" alt="{$server.name}" /></li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Also I have a form element named "sid" I was wondering how do I change the value of it to the ID of the selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the input element by using attribute selector and use `val()` method to set its value with the id of selected item.

```
$('[name="sid"]').val($(this).attr('id'));
```